# Past progressive’s special use

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, tense

The description below is about the special use of past progressive from *Practical English Usage*:

> The past progressive is quite often used with verbs of saying: this gives more relative importance to the following verb - to what is said.
> (Ex)  *Jack **was saying** that he still can’t find a job.*

I don’t understand the part of “more relative importance” because there is no explanation about this.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the construction **was saying** is most frequently used in a positive response by one person to something said by another, as in:

A: I saw a removal van parked outside the Smith's house this morning.
B: Yes, the postmistress was saying that their house has now been sold.

It would be grammatically correct to write: **Yes, the postmistress said...**
but using the past progressive both picks up on person A's remark and gives the impression that this continues to be the case - that the house has been sold.

More examples:

A: I know of three people in the village who have gone down with (the) flu.
B: Yes, the doctor was saying that it's a bad year for the flu.

A: I saw the postman with a young woman in the passenger seat of his van.
B: Yes, he was saying that he had to show a new employee the delivery route.

Comment: Yes - the situation continues to be the case, so the speaker may have said it more than once to different people.